Prove that $A\times B = \{{(a,b) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : a \in A, b \in B}\}$ is closed in $(\mathbb{R, d_E})$
Suppose $A,B \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ are closed in $(\mathbb{R, d_E})$ Prove that
$$A\times B = \{{(a,b) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : a \in A, b \in B}\}$$ is closed in $(\mathbb{R^2, d_E})$
I need help with this problem. I tried solving it but I did it entirely wrong and I need help knowing what I did wrong and how to fix it.
Proof.
$A,B \in \mathbb{R}$ are closed $\implies$ $\mathbb{R}\setminus A, \mathbb{R}\setminus B$ is open
Since $A,B$ are closed then they are sequentially closed, so there is a sequence $(a_n)$ in A that converges to a point $a \in \mathbb{R}$
such that $a=lim a_n \in A$. For $B$ it is the same where we have a sequence $(b_n)$ in $B$ that converges to a point $b \in \mathbb{R}$
such that $b=lim b_n \in B$.
Now we have $A\times B = \{{(a,b) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : a \in A, b \in B}\}$ and since $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}$
are in these sets, then both $a=lim a_n \in A$ and $b=lim b_n \in B$ are in these sets which are both sequentially closed, thuss $A \times B$ is sequentially closed because the limit points in it
are sequentially closed.

My bad I meant $(\mathbb{R^2}, d_E)$

Start the proof  with $(a_n,b_n)\to (a,b)$ where $(a_n,b_n)\in A \times B$ for every $n$.

Yeah I realized I should've done that, but I'm not sure exactly why. Why can't I just use the fact that A and B are sequentially closed to show that $A \times B$ is closed?

For this I think there's an approach that you can try and show that $\mathbb{R^2} \setminus (A \times B)$ is open to prove that $A \times B$ is closed and to do that
you must do some set algebra with the fact that $A,B \in \mathbb{R}$ are closed $\implies$ $\mathbb{R}\setminus A, \mathbb{R}\setminus B$ is open.
$\mathbb{R^2} \setminus (A \times B)$ = $\{(a,b) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : a \notin A \text{ or } b \notin B\}$
$= (\mathbb{R} \times (\mathbb{R} \setminus A)) \cup (\mathbb{R} \times (\mathbb{R} \setminus B))$. We can use this to conclude that the set is open to prove that $A \times B$ is closed.
The way I shouldve approached it by doing sequential compactness it by starting with the set $A \times B$ and using the fact that $(a_n, b_n) \rightarrow (a,b)$.
Please correct me if im wrong.

You seem to be confused about the difference between "sequentially closed" and "sequentially compact". Your original post doesn't mention compactness. The idea in your original post can be got to work if you work through it carefully using the definition of sequentially closedness (which is equivalent to closedness in metric spaces). Your answer above doesn't seem to solve your original problem satisfactorily: how can you use your equation for the complement of $A \times B$ to prove that $A \times B$ is closed.

... and your recent edit to your answer is moving in the right direction if you focus on sequential closedness rather than sequential compactness.
